# HTML: centering an image with a non-fix size

Tags: html, center

I want to make a simple thing in html, but don't find a solution. Maybe you can help me.

I have an empty Website () and want to put an image right in the middle of the page (vertical and horizontal). There a lots of solutions out there, which calculate the Position by the size of the image. The thing is, that I want to make the size of the image depend on the local screen-resolution.

The Image should ALWAYS fill 70% of screen-width, the height should stay proportional. Even if the User resizes the browser-window.

Best would be a solution with divs and css, but if neccessary, tables and html-formating is okay too.

Answer (score 1):

Can you have the image position absolute? Because its a dynamic image size you'll need some jquery assistance. To have the image resize properly:

```
img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
}
```

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    img_adjust($('img'));

    $(window).resize(function() {
       img_adjust($('img'));
    });
});

function img_adjust(image_obj) {
   var window_height = $(window).height();
   var image_height = image_obj.outerHeight();
   var margin_top = (window_height - image_height) / 2;

   image_obj.css('margin-top', margin_top + 'px');
}
```

Here is an example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/b4ttq/

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it without any javascript at all then you will not be able to center the image vertically, you just cant. This is the best pure html-css solution i can come up with. The following code will size the image to 70% of the width, height proportionally, and set the image 30% from the top;
html:

```
<div id='block'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='pic'>
   <img id='img' src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png' />
</div>
```

css:

```
 #block{
        height:30%;
        display: block;
    }
    #pic{
        display: block;
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-top: auto;
    }
    #img{
        width: 70%;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a div of 70% width, a margin-left 15%! That centers your container..
Do the same for the height accordingly!
To adapt the image size give a css `img {max-width:100%; height:auto;}`
That should do it..